# Rhino Mocks - Arg<T> to ommit some parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, arguments, parameter-passing, rhino-mocks

I am using Rhino Mocks to stub out the functionality of a SOAP endpoint and for the most part it works. But, the interface is quite quirky and I am struggling to get the following to work (i have renamed the classes for simplicity)

```
  public interface IWebService
    {
        void CopyFile(Request request);
    }

public interface IService
{
    void CopyFile(string filename, byte[] data);
}

public class Request
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
public class Service : IService
{
    IWebService _service;
    public Service(IWebService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
    public void CopyFile(string filename, byte[] data)
    {
        _service.CopyFile(new Request() {Filename = filename,Data = data });
    }
}
```

Now, in my test I have something like this

```
[TestCase]
        public void TestFileCopyFailsIfFilenameIsMissing()
        {
            IWebService serviceMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IWebService>();
            serviceMock.Expect(x => x.CopyFile(Arg<Request>.Is.Equal(new Request() { Filename = Arg<string>.Is.Null, Data = Arg<byte[]>.Is.Anything }))).Throw(new Exception());

            Service service = new Service(serviceMock);
            service.CopyFile(null, new byte[] { });

        }
```

Which throws the exception:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Rhino.Mocks.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Use Arg ONLY within a mock method call while recording. 1 arguments expected, 3 have been defined.

I have tried the all possibilities in the world on this one, but cant get it right. If i dont use Arg and use

```
Expect(null, new byte[]{});
```

it will always pass no matter what

Comment: I think you have to overide Equals method in Reqeust to make it work....or you have to seperately compare Filename and Data instead of whole request

Comment: Hi Viru, I cannot override Request as it is autogenerated by a tool every time the webservice is built and i am not the supplier of the web interface. Is there something else that can be done?

Comment: are you able to access FileName and Data property by doing something liek this Arg<Reqeust>.FileName?? Idea is if you are able to access specific property then compare those instead of whole request

Comment: I have to pass the Request type to the web service call, so I cant break it up at that point

Comment: Does Rhino Mock provides you with way to access property of passed argument while running test...this is what you should be looking for.

Comment: I have post code which I think will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `WhenCalled` and in this method check `Request` object.

```
        bool isCorrectParam = false;

        IWebService serviceMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IWebService>();
          serviceMock.Expect(x => x.CopyFile(null))
              .IgnoreArguments()
              .WhenCalled(x =>
              {
                  Request req = x.Arguments[0] as Request;
                  if (req.Data.Count() == 0 && req.Filename == null)
                  {
                      isCorrectParam = true;
                  }
              });

        Service service = new Service(serviceMock);
        service.CopyFile(null, new byte[] { });

        Assert.IsTrue(isCorrectParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Matches...

```
serviceMock.Expect(x => x.CopyFile(Arg<Request>.Matches(r => r.FileName==null))).Throw(new Exception());
```

Comment: Glad I could help...It will be kind if you accept answer :)

Comment: Please excuse my lack of competence, but I was actually looking for how to accept it but cant seem to find it. Not that experienced asking questions here

Comment: Just below vote option against my answer there will be tick option....Check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow